# Who is Hiranygarbha and what is the meaning of it?

Tags: name

Who is **Hiranygarbha**?

Is it a name of god? If yes, to which god it refers to?

What is the meaning of the word Hiranygarbha?

Comment: [Should I search on Internet before asking question?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/224)

Comment: @sv. I searched for it, but there is a conflict between Vishnu and Brahma.

Answer (score 5):

The name 'HiraNyagarbha' is found in the HiraNyagarbhasukta of the Rig-Veda (10/121) that reads

> hiraNyagarbhah samavartata agre bhtasya jatah patireka Asit/sa dAdhAra prithivim dyAm utemAm kasmai devAya habisha bidhema//

HiraNyagarbha means

> That SutrAtmA, in whose belly/womb ('garbha') the golden ('HiraNmaya') world (BrahmANda) is present. He is mentioned as the Lord ('Pati') of the world.

He is sometimes referred to as BrahmA : the creator form of God. In other places, He is also interpreted as the Primal Form of Brahman.

According t sanskritdictionary.com,([https://www.sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=iast&q=ह](https://www.sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=iast&q=%E0%A4%B9)िरण्यगर्भ&lang=sans&action=Search) the word means

> the soul invested with the Sūkṣma-śarira or subtle body (Monier-Williams, Sir M. (1988))
>   a golden fetus (Monier-Williams, Sir M. (1988))

**UPDATE**

In his commentary on the Svetasvatara-Upanishad, Narayana defines HiraNyagarva as

> hiraNyagarvam yasya brahmaNdam sariram, yadgarvo virAtpurusho brahmaNdapanchikritapanchabhutArabhdham ----meaning that HiraNyagarva means He, Whose body is the entire world, The All-pervading One Who holds everything within Him, and Who has created the five bhutas by the five tattvas.

Reference:Stavakusumanjaii, Swami Gambhirananda, Udbodhan, page 22, page 85.

Answer (score 3):

Hiraṇyagarbha literally translates as "the golden womb" and refers to the creator of the universe.

The Hiraṇyagarbha Sukta (Rig-Veda 10.121) identifies Hiraṇyagarbha as Prajapati i.e. Brahma:

> 1. **In the beginning rose Hiranyagarbha, born Only Lord of all created beings.**
>       **He fixed and holdeth up this earth and heaven.** What God shall we adore with our oblation?
> 2. Giver of vital breath, of power and vigour, he whose commandments all the Gods acknowledge -.
>       The Lord of death, whose shade is life immortal. What God shall we adore with our oblation?
> 3. Who by his grandeur hath become Sole Ruler of all the moving world that breathes and slumbers;
>       He who is Lord of men and Lord of cattle. What God shall we adore with our oblation?
> 4. His, through his might, are these snow-covered mountains, and men call sea and Rasa his possession:
>       His arms are these, his are these heavenly regions. What God shall we adore with our oblation?
> 5. By him the heavens are strong and earth is stedfast, by him light's realm and sky-vault are supported:
>       By him the regions in mid-air were measured. What God shall we adore with our oblation?
> 6. To him, supported by his help, two armies embattled look while trembling in their spirit,
>       When over them the risen Sun is shining. What God shall we adore with our oblation?
> 7. What time the mighty waters came, containing the universal germ, producing Agni,
>       Thence sprang the Gods' one spirit into being. What God shall we adore with our oblation?
> 8. He in his might surveyed the floods containing productive force and generating Worship.
>       He is the God of gods, and none beside him. What God shall we adore with our oblation?
> 9. Neer may he harm us who is earth's Begetter, nor he whose laws are sure, the heavens' Creator,
>       He who brought forth the great and lucid waters. What God shall we adore with our oblation?
> 10. **Prajapati! thou only comprehendest all these created things, and none beside thee**.
>        Grant us our hearts' desire when we invoke thee: may we have store of riches in possession.

Comment: @prajapati in the vedas does not necessarily mean BrahmA

Comment: What can it mean other than Brahma? @Pratimaputra